# Using XQuery with multiple collection functions

Tags: collections, xquery

I am using the following XQuery to query a collection of files:

```
for $files in collection("/data?select=*data*.xml")
```

Each file in the directory has a specific name, which enables me to recognize it. I use this as the identifier, which I retrieve as follows:

```
let $file-id := tokenize(base-uri($files), "/")[last()]
```

The *$file-id* variable follows a certain pattern: abc-1234. The first eight characters are relevant, so I fetch them using the variable below:

```
let $file-link-id := substring($file-id, 1, 8)
```

Now, I have another collection of files, which I want to query. These files follow the same pattern in the name, because they contain connected information.

How can I use the *$file-link-id* to select the correct file in the second collection?

I assume I would have to include it in the second collection clause, something along the lines of `?select=$file-link-id.xml`, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could clearify your problem statement if I assume wrong here, because your problem seems to be very easy solveable (so maybe I misunderstood your problem).

So you have your correct `$file-link-id` and want to use it as string. If your xquery processor supports XQuery 3.0 you can use two pipes, i.e.

```
for $files in collection("/data?select=" || $file-link-id || ".xml")
```

If not, use `string-join()`:

```
for $files in collection(string-join(("/data?select=", $file-link-id, ".xml"), ''))
```